# What is/are Trinity bowls?

Tags: biographical-details

In his forward to Hardy's *Apology,* C. P. Snow remarks that after his (Hardy's) 1939 heart attack, Hardy "recovered enough ... to play his pleasing elaboration (with a complicated set of bisques) of Trinity bowls." From what I have been able to determine, Trinity bowls was probably a form of lawn bowling, and bisques a sort of "free turn" for players of lesser skill. I'm assuming that the "complicated set" refers to a complicated set of conditions under which the "free turns" might be taken. Can anyone illuminate me on this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Bowls, just like golf and croquet, has a system for handicapping players. I would guess that the number of bisques (free turns) would be a function of a player's handicap and that it would be at the player's discretion during to course of a match as to when they use these free turns.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not related to history of science.

Comment: @AChem - I have no problem with your vote to close. I realize my question is very tenuously related to the history of science. However, when reading a preface written half a century earlier, especially one so context specific, obscure references such as "Trinity bowls" do raise curiosity. It doesn't help that all the principals are now dead, so direct inquiry is not possible.